# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'profileaccount'

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error and I want to return a model profileaccounts.id but it is not within WSGIRequest. 
Is there a way to find all the objects with WSGIRequest?

### ERROR LOG

AttributeError at /2/detail/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'profileaccount'

Views.py

```
class ProfileAccountDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = ProfileAccount

    fields = [
        'first_name',
        'family_name',
        'email',
        'account_active',
    ]
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "profiles:detail",
            kwargs={'pk': self.request.profileaccount.id},
        )
    def get_object(self):
        return ProfileAccount.objects.get(
            pk=self.request.profileaccount.id

        )
```

This is my models file. I want to access profileaccount.id in the request.

Models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

from autoslug import AutoSlugField
from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel


class ProfileAccount(TimeStampedModel):

    # fields manually completed by introducer - automatically copied if user_for_self is True
    first_name = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=150)
    family_name = models.CharField("Family Name", max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField("Email Address", max_length=200, null=True)

    # set when user_for_self is True  and payment successful and current
    account_active = models.BooleanField("Account Actived", default="False")

    # currently not used but might be required if i can get it to work
    slug = AutoSlugField("Account Slug",
        unique=True, always_update=False, populate_from="first_name")

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.family_name)



class ProfileLink(TimeStampedModel):

    class Relationship(models.TextChoices):
        USER = "user", "User"
        INTRODUCER = "introducer", "Introducer"
        ASSISTANT = "assistant", "Assistant"
        COMPLIANCE = "compliance", "Compliance"

    # links to account and user automatically completed
    account = models.ForeignKey(ProfileAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # fields required during Profile Account creation
    user_for_self = models.BooleanField("For self", default="False")
    user_assist = models.BooleanField("Assistance required", default="False")

    # fields intially given a value that can be changed by the profile account owner
    user_access = models.BooleanField("Can user access", default="False")
    user_type = models.CharField('Relationship', max_length=50,
        choices=Relationship.choices, default=Relationship.INTRODUCER)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.account
```

Comment: Try `self.request.user.profileaccount.id`. Your `get_object(self)` method could be simplified to `return self.request.user.profileaccount`. A `DetailView` does not need a success_url, so you can remove the `get_success_url` method.

Comment: Hi, 
I changed it to self.request.user.profileaccount but it still says 'User' object has no attribute 'profileaccount'. Can you tell me how to resolve this. Is there any way to find all the objects within the user?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? You want to render the data in you template

Comment: Yes, I've a model called profileaccount, i want to return that id e.g profileaccount.id

Comment: Please show your `ProfileAccount` model.

Comment: `
class ProfileAccount(TimeStampedModel):

    first_name = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=150)
    family_name = models.CharField("Family Name", max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField("Email Address", max_length=200, null=True)

    account_active = models.BooleanField("Account Actived", default="False")

    slug = AutoSlugField("Account Slug",
        unique=True, always_update=False, populate_from="first_name")

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.family_name)

`

Comment: I've pasted over here. 
https://pastebin.com/fTvM1HWQ

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the model there. It's hard to read code in the comments, and inconvenient to go to another site to see it.

Comment: Normally your profile model would have a one-to-one field to your `User` model. Then `self.request.user.profileaccount` would work. See [this blog post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#a-nameonetooneaextending-user-model-using-a-one-to-one-link) for more details. At the moment, there's no way to tell which profile belongs to the logged-in user.

Comment: @Alasdair How can I find all the objects within the user? e.g something print("self.request.user") ??

Comment: Python lets you do `dir`, e.g. `print(dir(self.request.user))`. The docs on [Many-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships) might help you. You could try something like `ProfileLink.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, user_type='USER').get().account`. The link is a bit complex so you might have to change the `user_type` filtering, and handle the cases when there a many/no profiles for the user.

Comment: Having `class Relationship` inside `class ProfileLink` is strange, I don't understand what's going on there.

Comment: @Alasdair How do I connect user to profileaccount's id?

Comment: When I printed the dir, i cant find profile account model there

Comment: There isn't a direct link from user to profile - it looks like they are joined by profile link. I already suggested that you use `ProfileLink.objects.filter(...)` - I can't help you any more than that because I don't understand what's going on with ProfileLink/Relationship/user_type.